# Uncountably many disjoint dense subsets in $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Show that, there are uncountably many disjoint dense subsets in $\Bbb{R}$.

I know $\Bbb{Q}$ is a dense subset in $\Bbb{R}$. But other than this and disjoint to $\Bbb{Q},$ I have no idea.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\Bbb R$ given by $x\sim y$ iff $x-y\in \Bbb Q$. Using axiom of choice, from each equivalence class take a representative and consider the corresponding translate of $\Bbb Q$. Note that any translation of $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.

Actually, any equivalence class can be written as $i+\Bbb Q$ for some $i\in \Bbb R\backslash \Bbb Q$, in particular any equivalence class is countable. So, there are uncountably many equivalence classes, as countable union of countably many sets is countable, but $\Bbb R$ is uncountable.

Note another fact, $i+\Bbb Q=(i+r)+\Bbb Q$ for any $r\in \Bbb Q$ and any $i\in \Bbb R\backslash \Bbb Q$. In other words, two distinct irrational translates of $\Bbb Q$ may give same equivalence class. That's why we need to consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ to get uncountably many disjoint dense subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Why $\Bbb Q$? Because, it is a countable dense subgroup of $(\Bbb R,+)$. So, we may replace $\Bbb Q$ by some other countable dense subgroup, for example, the set of all dyadic rationals $\big\{\frac{m}{2^n}\big| m,n\in \Bbb Z\text{ and }n\geq 0\big\}.$