# Show that R has uncountable number of dense subsets

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Following comes Topology Without Tears by Morris

Let S and T be non-empty subsets of a topological space (X, τ) with S ⊆ T.

(iii)  if S is dense in X, then T is dense in X.

What I want to prove is:

**Show that R has uncountable number of dense
subsets using(iii).**

Comments:
Since S is uncountable P(S) is uncountable
so no bijection exists.I can’t see how a
bijection exists.

**Try**

Let S={$a+b\sqrt{2}$,a,b$\in N$,
$a+b\pi$,a,b$\in N$}

Let the set T={Q$\cup$$ Q^{c}$ ,(Q$\cup I)^{c}$ $\cup $ (Q $\cup $ I)}

So each set in S is distinct uncountable and
dense in R

So each set in T is distinct uncountable and
dense in R

Since S$\subset T$ and by (iii) this shows
there are $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ dense sets

If I have walked off the “deep end”, I would
like to know how to do this stuff correctly.

Comment: [$\Bbb R$ has uncountably many pairwise disjoint dense subsets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733964/uncountably-many-disjoint-dense-subsets-in-bbbr/3733970#3733970)

Comment: @Sumanta Das - that's interesting but difficult to understand. OP didn't ask for disjoint subsets.

Comment: Ahh sorry. I have not read the question properly, just heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple.

$ \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}.$

The function $f: \mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(i) = \mathbb{Q} \cup \{i\}$ is injective *and* the domain is uncountable, therefore the [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)) is also uncountable. *Every* element in the image of $f$ is a superset of $\mathbb{Q}$, which we know is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

So by $(iii)$, the image of $f$ is a collection of uncountable dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: So I guess I walked off the “deep end”

Comment: Yes, you did. It happens to me often lol. If you required your subsets to be *disjoint* then the question would be more difficult, but you didn’t ask for that.

Comment: This is where I got the idea:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3941678/830852 @AdamRubinson

Comment: The theorem doesn’t state it either way

Answer (score 0):

Union $\mathbb{Q}$ with a given irrational number to get a set T, certainly T is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (this works since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable implies that the irrationals form an uncountable set).

Comment: You mean for eg. Let T={Q$\cup\pi$} so T is dense in R.